# Rails sanitize method replaces single quotes with double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

The rails sanitize method replaces single quotes with double quotes when anchor tags are seen.

Example

```
sanitize("<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>")
=> "<a href=\"https://google.com\">google</a>"
```

This is problematic because in my application, I'm sanitizing JSON payloads that can contain these strings, which causes the JSON to be malformed.

```
JSON.parse("{\"link\":\"<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>\"}")
=> {"link"=>"<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>"}

JSON.parse(sanitize(("{\"link\":\"<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>\"}"))
=> JSON::ParseError
```

I don't have any control over the input string. Is there any way to prevent the conversion of single to double quotes?

Comment: Why don't you sanitize just the user input (I don't think keys are user input) instead of the complete json?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Instead of sanitizing the complete json, you can just sanitize the user inputs first, and then create a json from that:

```
link_html = "<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>"
data = {"link" => sanitize(link_html)}.to_json
```

It will create a json like this:

```
"{\"link\":\"<a href=\\\"https://google.com\\\">google</a>\"}"
```

On the receiving end JSON.parse will work just fine:

```
irb(main):009:0> JSON.parse("{\"link\":\"<a href=\\\"https://google.com\\\">google</a>\"}")
=> {"link"=>"<a href=\"https://google.com\">google</a>"}
```

Comment: no, 
because the user can be evil. 
For example they can write a partial json that ends your data-link and add new fields after them.

Comment: Then probably you should sanitize the user input first, and then create the json. I have updated the answer.